# Using substr with URLs

Tags: php, hyperlink, substr

I am outputting a string using the substr function and limiting the output to 100 characters. The problem is sometimes the string contains a URL with over 100 characters.

Does anyone have any advice on how I can output the URL within the 100 character limit by replacing the text link to something generic like [Link]

My code:

```
        <?php
            $reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
            if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $content, $url)) {
                $content = preg_replace($reg_exUrl, "<a href=\"{$url[0]}\" target=\"_blank\">Link</a>", $content);
                if (strlen($content) > 100) {
                    echo substr($content, 0, 100).'...';
                }
            } else {
                if (strlen($content) > 100) { echo substr(stripslashes($content), 0, 100).'...'; } else { echo stripslashes($content); }
            }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(strlen($url[0]) > 100) {
   $content = preg_replace($reg_exUrl, "<a href=\"{$url[0]}\" target=\"_blank\">Link</a>", $content);
}else{
   $content = preg_replace($reg_exUrl, "<a href=\"{$url[0]}\" target=\"_blank\">{$url[0]}</a>", $content);
}
```